# Excepción por creación de childview en Loop

Tags: android, bucles, views

Me encuentro realizando creaciones de nuevas vistas desde el archivo java en Android Studio. Para ello he realizado el siguiente Loop.

```
    LinearLayout numbersLayout = findViewById(R.id.numbersLayout);
    TextView numberTextView1 = new TextView(this);

    int i = 0;
    while (i < numbers.size()){

        numberTextView1.setText(numbers.get(i));
        numberTextView1.setPadding(7,7,0,7);
        //numberTextView1.setTextAppearance(R.style.Fuentes);
        numberTextView1.setTextSize(16);
        numbersLayout.addView(numberTextView1);
        i++;
    }
```

Sin embargo me manda el siguiente error:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a >parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

Me gustaría encontrarle alguna explicación ya que cuando ingreso la línea de creación del objeto `numberTextView1` al loop el problema desaparece.

```
    LinearLayout numbersLayout = findViewById(R.id.numbersLayout);

    int i = 0;
    while (i < numbers.size()){

        TextView numberTextView1 = new TextView(this);
        numberTextView1.setText(numbers.get(i));
        numberTextView1.setPadding(7,7,0,7);
        //numberTextView1.setTextAppearance(R.style.Fuentes);
        numberTextView1.setTextSize(16);
        numbersLayout.addView(numberTextView1);
        i++;
    }
```

Comment: `El hijo especificado ya tiene un padre. Debe llamar removeView() en el padre del hijo primero.` (suena medio raro en español). En el primer caso creas una nueva vista con `new TextView` y por cada iteración estás intentando añadir la misma vista a `numbersLayout` y por eso del error, es decir, deberías remover ese `TextView` con `removeView()`  para poder añadir el siguiente. En el segundo caso en cada iteración creas una nueva vista y por ende el problema como dices tú desaparece.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta Fabián ¿Lo que hago es chancar la vista creada con cada `new TextView` cierto? Esa fue la razón por la que se me ocurrió sacarlo del Loop.